# Processing: In the following code, what does x= x + 1 do?

Tags: processing

When running this code, the rectangle 'moves' from left to right.

- How does the code `x = x + 1` generates this?
- How does it keep creating rectangles one pixel further on the x-axis?

```java
void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  stroke(255);
  background(192, 64, 0);
} 

int hoogte = 50;
int breedte = 50;
int x = 50;

void draw () {
  rect(x,100, breedte, hoogte);
  stroke(181);
  x = x + 1;
}
```

Result of running the code
[image]

Comment: What specifically about that are you asking about? `x = x + 1;` just adds 1 to `x`. "x is equal to x plus one".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the `draw()` function is called 60 times per second.

The `x = x + 1` line adds one to the `x` variable. Since you're drawing your rectangle based on the `x` variable, the rectangle moves across the screen over time.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing) is a tutorial explaining animation in Processing.